# Pushing Windows Store apps silently

Tags: windows, windows-8

As part of a requirement I have been issued, I seek the ability to push apps from the Windows Store (.appx) to remote users.
The framework surrounding the data transmission is sorted; What I need to know is if there is a script that can be sent out along with a URI or the package proper to facilitate installation on the user-side of the Windows Store app.

I am well aware that numerous guides exist from Microsoft on pushing out Line-of-Business (LOB) (AKA Enterprise) applications -- that is, apps that have been developed in-house and are not for the consumption of the Windows store. This is inappropriate for my requirement, however; the customer wants their clients to receive apps that appear currently on the Windows Store, and for them to be installed in a silent manner.

I've seen this guide; http://blogs.technet.com/b/keithmayer/archive/2013/02/25/step-by-step-deploying-windows-8-apps-with-system-center-2012-service-pack-1.aspx, which details doing exactly this, but it is only applicable to machines that are administered by a system running Windows Server 2012 R2 with the 'System Center 2012' bundle installed. The systems I target are considerably more decentralised than this, making this guide inappropriate.

I have a hunch that Microsoft have deliberately designed the Windows Store to be this way, but I figured I ought to ask around before I resign myself to the requirement.

Much obliged

Comment: This official article should get you started: [Sideload Windows Store Apps in Windows 8](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dn613831.aspx)

Comment: Alright, I'll give them a go. Cheers.

Comment: For reference: the guide posted here details sideloading of LOB apps, but not production-ready Microsoft-signed apps.

Answer (score 1):

If you have the .appx package file, you can install it via powershell with the `Add-AppxPackage` cmdlet.

http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh856048.aspx

Comment: I'll look into this and let you know if it's what I'm looking for -- thanks.